# Why does Symfony2 set the error_reporting?

Tags: symfony

I've been trying to remove the E_NOTICE and E_STRICT error levels to avoid this error:

```
Runtime Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference
```

I tried modifying php.ini but didn't work, error_reporting always is -1. Then I tried setting it dynamically in the current action, and worked fine. Then I also tried the same in the first line in app_dev.php and didn't work. Which means Symfony2 is setting it dynamically somewhere.

What should I do?

**EDIT**

For those who are not familiar with the error:

```
$user = $this->('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

$first = reset($user->getRoles()); // error

$roles = $user->getRoles();
$first = reset($roles); // works fine
```

Comment: You should account the notice message ;)

Comment: That's hardly a retarded error, it's quite an error you should fix.

Comment: Do you even know when this error occurs? I updated my question. Now tell me how this error makes sense.

Comment: That is a valid notice, still. reset takes a reference, and the return value from your function is a _copy_ of the array in its return statement. As such it is necessary to assign the value to something before resetting.

Comment: If it's an error then why does it work after removing the notice?

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper Whilst it might be a notice and it would _work_, what it's suggesting is that the reset call has essentially no effect, which is likely not what you intended.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper I'm not sure you understand what are notices for...

Comment: What I intended is to get the first element.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper why not use `$user->getRoles()->first()`?

Comment: @Inori Because it is an array, not an ArrayIterator.

Comment: fair enough, why not define `getFirstRole` method in user entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst the notice is not 'retarded', this is a reasonable question in other contexts so: this is set in the Kernel instance, instantiated in app_dev.php (or app.php).

The second parameter to the construct is a boolean debug flag, and if `true` then `error_reporting` is set to -1 and `display_errors` to 1, otherwise default and 0 respectively.

`$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', false);`

symfony [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, but the error remains retarded. Reset() is meant to return the first element. Sure I could use current() since the array is a new copy, but what if it wasn't? There are 99999 array functions in php, and yet, I have to write an extra line of code only because of this error.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper That is only one of reset()'s behaviours, and that is the crux of the problem in this case. Bottom line is that such notices are there to help you write better code, and that's why Symfony turns 'em all on. HTH.

Comment: In file web/app_dev.php: `$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', false);`

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error in the following scenario i.e.

**Scenario:** 
I lost the development environment for my existing LIVE project. But I got the whole code from GIT repo and then installed the symfony 2.4.2 (same version as on LIVE site) in my new development environment. Then I found that the web-application pages working on the LIVE site are broken in my new DEV environment.

**Solution:**
I spent quit a lot time to understand why the problem is then I found that i.e.

When I installed symfony 2.4.2 in my development environment using composer.phar then it created a new **web/app_dev.php** file in my development environment and it has the following entry to turn it off i.e.

**Debug::enable()**;

Just **comment the above line** then the php notices will be off and then all the pages that were giving me notices are fixed.

I hope this will be helpful for someone having the same problem like me. Good Luck!

Cheers.

PS: But I will recommend to enable the above line in your new development projects so that you can see the PHP notices and then remove them during development.